# What is the correct way to make translations available between apps in a microfrontend architecture?

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, webpack-module-federation

I work on a project built in nx that uses the microfrontend architecture. The application consists of a host app and a series of remote apps in addition to common libraries. The app uses translations, for this purpose I use `nxg-translation`. In the host app I configure the translation module in `app.module.ts`

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
   return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}

TranslateModule.forRoot({
   defaultLanguage: 'en',
   loader: {
     provide:TranslateLoader,
     useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
     deps: [HttpClient],
   },
})
```

in `apps/host/src/assets` I have created the `i18n` directory along with the `en.json` and `es.json` files

If I use the host app when visiting the remote app, the translations work properly

But I serve a remote app individually, the translations do not work

To solve this behavior I want to use a common library, in which to place the translation `.json` files and invoke them from all the apps

The first problem I found is that the files to be exported are `.json` and I don't know how to export these files from the `index.ts` file of the library

Could you suggest me what is the appropriate approach in this scenario?

Thanks in advance for any ideas